# Ploting "real size" figures in matplotlib (scrollbars instead of zooming)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with plotting in matplotlib. I need to plot a wide figure which represents an allocation of radio resources in time. But when a time period is big, the plot shrinks and I need to zoom it to see what is in particular fragment. 
What I want, is to plot the data without scaling ("real size") and to use the scrollbars to scroll the plot horizontally (in time). Is that possible?

Comment: You may produce an image of your plot of arbitrary size and then use your favorite program to view it. I don't think any of the matplotlib backends supports scrollbars -- of course, you may just zoom in and use the hand tool to scroll...

Comment: Okay, so I assume, that I need to use:

fig.set_size_inches(XX,YY)
fig.savefig('filename')

And that seems to work, but is there any way to set the saved figure size as 1:1 size? Because it can be difficult to determine which size should I use for the next plot, and I will need to chenge script every time (or pass additional arg)?

Comment: What do you mean by 1:1 size? What units are you using to specify your plot? And how shall those units relate to the pixels displayed by your screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example from a scipy cookbook:

> When plotting a very long sequence in a matplotlib canvas embedded in
> a wxPython application, it sometimes is useful to be able to display a
> portion of the sequence without resorting to a scrollable window so
> that both axes remain visible. Here is how to do so:

```py
from numpy import arange, sin, pi, float, size

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent, id, 'scrollable plot',
                style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER,
                size=(800, 400))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.fig = Figure((5, 4), 75)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self.panel, -1, self.fig)
        self.scroll_range = 400
        self.canvas.SetScrollbar(wx.HORIZONTAL, 0, 5,
                                 self.scroll_range)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.canvas, -1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.panel.Fit()

        self.init_data()
        self.init_plot()

        self.canvas.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, self.OnScrollEvt)

    def init_data(self):

        # Generate some data to plot:
        self.dt = 0.01
        self.t = arange(0,5,self.dt)
        self.x = sin(2*pi*self.t)

        # Extents of data sequence: 
        self.i_min = 0
        self.i_max = len(self.t)

        # Size of plot window:       
        self.i_window = 100

        # Indices of data interval to be plotted:
        self.i_start = 0
        self.i_end = self.i_start + self.i_window

    def init_plot(self):
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.plot_data = \
                  self.axes.plot(self.t[self.i_start:self.i_end],
                                 self.x[self.i_start:self.i_end])[0]

    def draw_plot(self):

        # Update data in plot:
        self.plot_data.set_xdata(self.t[self.i_start:self.i_end])
        self.plot_data.set_ydata(self.x[self.i_start:self.i_end])

        # Adjust plot limits:
        self.axes.set_xlim((min(self.t[self.i_start:self.i_end]),
                           max(self.t[self.i_start:self.i_end])))
        self.axes.set_ylim((min(self.x[self.i_start:self.i_end]),
                            max(self.x[self.i_start:self.i_end])))

        # Redraw:                  
        self.canvas.draw()

    def OnScrollEvt(self, event):

     # Update the indices of the plot:
        self.i_start = self.i_min + event.GetPosition()
        self.i_end = self.i_min + self.i_window + event.GetPosition()
        self.draw_plot()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(parent=None,id=-1)
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

- The example needs `wxPython`, `numpy` and `matplotlib`; `pip install numpy matplotlib wxPython` to install them.

Source: https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_ScrollingPlot.html

Comment: Can you give more detail than a link?

Comment: I agree, your answer is spot on... I guess I was looking for a quick summary of *how* it does it, in case the scipy site was down. But looking at the code, it seems like saying more than "using a wxPython application" would involve a word for word explaining what the code does. +1 for the right answer, I was just sharing my impressions of the answer.

Comment: OK, you're right in that it's worth saying a couple of words rather than just a link. An explanation of what a code does is indeed not worth it, but a one-sentence preamble is.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for my long absence. But now I'm back ;) This link is exactly what I was looking for, but still do not cover all of my needs... but this is a topic for later. I have tried to combine this code, with my plotting code - see edited question.

Comment: the link doesn't work. They seemed to have removed the scrolling plot example. I searched the cookbook and nothing came up. Do you know any other sources for this problem ? Please help.

Comment: @ev-br This link is being redirected, can't find it anymore.