# Plotting the data with scrollable x (time/horizontal) axis on Linux

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I want to plot data where x axis is long. If I plot the whole x axis then the plot shrinks and it is almost unreadable. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258534/ploting-real-size-figures-in-matplotlib-scrollbars-instead-of-zooming) answer on SO which points to [following](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/ScrollingPlot?action=show) scipy/matplotlib code. But When I try to run the mentioned code I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrollingPlot.py", line 88, in <module>
    app = MyApp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py", line 8628, in __init__
    self._BootstrapApp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py", line 8196, in _BootstrapApp
    return _core_.PyApp__BootstrapApp(*args, **kwargs)
  File "scrollingPlot.py", line 82, in OnInit
    self.frame = MyFrame(parent=None,id=-1)
  File "scrollingPlot.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.scroll_range)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py", line 11226, in SetScrollbar
    return _core_.Window_SetScrollbar(*args, **kwargs)
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "sb" failed at ../src/gtk/window.cpp(4754) in SetScrollbar(): this window is not scrollable
```

PS: Other solutions are also welcomed (preferably python, R, or something simple and multi platform)

PPS: I've opened the [issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4988) for mentioned error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you considered using matplotlib [slider widgets](https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Slider)?

Here is a little code just to show as example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

t = np.arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.1)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
l, = plt.plot(t,s)
plt.axis([0, 10, -1, 1])

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axpos = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

spos = Slider(axpos, 'Pos', 0.1, 90.0)

def update(val):
    pos = spos.val
    ax.axis([pos,pos+10,-1,1])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

spos.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

In `R` [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19154725/3285115) could help you. It will save the plot as a separate png, but you can change the format type with a different command. The relevant code from that answer is reproduced:

```
 png("wide.png", width = 1e5, height = 500)
 plot((sin(1:10000/100)+rnorm(10000)/5),type='l')
 dev.off()
 #bmp("wide.bmp", width = 1e5, height = 500)
 #plot((sin(1:10000/100)+rnorm(10000)/5),type='l')
 #dev.off()
 #note that the png has a size of 396 KB, while the bmp has 48,830 KB.
```

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting idea. It might come handy if matplotlib is not available otherwise the @Noel Segura solution seems fine.