# Scroll bar in Matplotlib live update

Tags: matplotlib

I can achieve the following:

1. GetData function keeps to run and generate data in 24x7 hours. The GetData will yield two values. The `time` is the x-array, the `value` is the y-array.
2. Import into plot class and plot it in real-time.

The window will keep moving(from left to right) and the x window will maintain 5 minutes(`xmax-xmin=datetime.detlta(minutes=5`)). The old data will invisible. 
If I don't set the xlim, the plot will huddle together and it will not be  so inaesthetic.

That is to say, when the plot is updating in the real-time, I can scroll back to the previous data to see the "history data".

I understand that we can save the plot to image with `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig`. Is there any other suggestions? May I know if there is a scroll bar under Matplotlib with the real-time update?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015755/datetime-with-slider-widget-in-matplotlib),  the final answer is as following.

As the question stats, the x is the timestamp, append a new data into the list.

```
    self.timestampRange = [min(self.timestamp1), max(self.timestamp1) + dt.timedelta(minutes=0.1)]  # datetime style
    self.loadingValueRange = [min(self.loadingValue), max(self.loadingValue) + 1]
```

Then set up the Slider and write an update function. Just need to notice the type of the x-array.

```
#Slider setting
    self.ssb = Slider(self.axsb, 'Scrollbar',
                              dates.date2num(self.timestampRange[0]),
                              dates.date2num(self.timestampRange[1]))
    self.ssb.on_changed(self.update)

    def update(self,val):
        self.sb=self.ssb.val
        self.xmin_time=dates.num2date(self.sb)-dt.timedelta(minutes=1)
        self.xmax_time=dates.num2date(self.sb)
        self.loadingGraph.axis([self.xmin_time,self.xmax_time,min(self.loadingValueRange), max(self.loadingValueRange)])
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

Hope it helps. Thanks.