# How to create multiple plots with scrollable x axis with a single slider

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, dashboard, ipywidgets

I intend to create 2-3 plots shared on a common time axis that can interactively scrolled with a single slider . Also there is one constraint where in sampling frequency is different for each variable but have the same time window.

```
x  - time
y1 - values sampled every 1 second
y2 - values sampled every 10 seconds
y3 - values sampled every 100 seconds
```

How can we do this .

Have tried this sample code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact
%matplotlib inline

def f(n):
    plt.plot([0,1,2],[0,1,n])
    plt.show()
interact(f,n=(0,10))
```

I want something similar to this , the only change being x and y axis data is constant and the slider widget is used to scroll the graph left and right (x axis here) with a certain time window on the graph display

Comment: What have you tried so far? This may be problem that has a few different issues, that would be better broken down into individual questions. Is there a place where something isn't behaving as expected? What does you data look like, can you provide a small example?

Comment: You should start writing code and if you have a specific question, you should ask it on SO. You can adapt codes on SO like this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31001713/8881141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snippet of the implementation below.

1. Load all the graphs and manipulate only the xlim with plt.xlim(min_x,max_x) with the slider functionality

   ```
   selection_range_slider = widgets.SelectionRangeSlider(
   options=options,
   index=index,
   description='Time slider',
   orientation='horizontal',
   layout={'width': '1000px'},
   continuous_update=False
   )

   #selection_range_slider
   def print_date_range(date_range):
       print(date_range)
       plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(15, 4), dpi=80, facecolor='w', 
       edgecolor='k')


       min_x=date_range[0]
       max_x=date_range[1]

       ax1 = plt.subplot(311)
       plt.plot(Data_1.Timestamp,Data_1.value,'r')
       plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=6,visible=False)
       plt.xlabel('Data_1')
       ax1.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.05, 0.5)


       # share x only
       ax2 = plt.subplot(312, sharex=ax1)
       plt.plot(Data_2.Timestamp,Data_2.value,'b')
       # make these tick labels invisible
       plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
       plt.xlabel('Data_2')
       ax2.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.05, 0.5)

       # share x and y
       ax3 = plt.subplot(313, sharex=ax1)
       plt.plot(Data_3.Timestamp,Data_3.value,'g')
       ax3.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.05, 0.5)

       #plt.xlim(0.01, 5.0)
       plt.xlim(min_x,max_x)
       plt.show()
       #plt.xlabel('Data_3')

   widgets.interact(
       print_date_range,
       date_range=selection_range_slider
       );
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem partially for the interactivity bit of it.

X axis is scrollable with the slider movement.

```
%matplotlib inline
from ipywidgets import interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(m):
    plt.figure(2)
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=1000)
    plt.plot(x,x)
    #plt.plot(x, m * x)
    plt.xlim(m+2, m-2)
    plt.show()

interactive(f, m=(-2.0, 2.0))
```