# Max number of ticks and scroll X

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, axis-labels

I would like define the max number of ticks on x axis, let's say 8, so the plot doesn't become like the image below:

[image]

This plot have an animation over time, and the data on x axis will increase 'forever'.

But I wouldn't like to lose the old data, I'm thinking scroll on x axis, maybe like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001713/plotting-the-data-with-scrollable-x-time-horizontal-axis-on-linux).

I already tried but I can't fit the solution to this case:

```
import requests as r
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def data_gen(t=0):
    while True:
        t += int(time.time())
        yield t, int(r.get('https://qrng.anu.edu.au/API/jsonI.php?length=1&type=uint8&size=6&time=1533249361313').json()['data'][0])

def run(data):
    t, y = data
    xdata.append(t)
    ydata.append(y)
    x_labels.append(time.strftime('%H:%m:%S'))
    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
    plt.xticks(xdata, x_labels, rotation=20)
    if t >= xmax or y >= ymax:
        if t >= xmax:
            ax.set_xlim(0, t+(t/10))
        if y >= ymax:
            ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax+50)
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return line,


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [])
ax.grid()
xdata, ydata, x_labels = [0], [0], [time.strftime('%H:%m:%S')]

ax.set_ylim(0, 250)
ax.set_xlim(int(time.time()), int(time.time())+10)
line.set_data(xdata, ydata)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, data_gen, blit=False, interval=10,
                              repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The maximum number of ticks matplotlib will show by default is lower than 8, if you don't plot strings.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I just want a readable data on x axis after n times new data arrives, without losing the 'old' data

Comment: yes and in order to achieve that you should not plot strings, but `datetime` objects.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you , I will try but what do I do about the old data that I must see if I want?

Comment: The question you link to seems to do exactly that. Maybe you want to explain what problem there is in implementing such solution?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I will implement datetime objs, and then I try from there