# Matplotlib dynamic plot with a slider

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

I'm not too used to `matplotlib` dynamic plots, and thus I have some difficulties to create a desired plot. I'm trying to plot N timelines (not too much, less say less than 5) of the same large size (800k points). I would like to use a slider to represent this.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

plt.ioff()

timelines = [np.random.randint(-2, 5, size = 800000),
             np.random.randint(-2, 5, size = 800000), 
             np.random.randint(-2, 5, size = 800000)]
timelines_labels = ["label1", "label2", "label3"]

def slide_plot(timelines, timelines_labels):

    f, ax = plt.subplots(len(timelines), 1, sharex = True, figsize = (20, 10))

    def update(pos, ax = ax, timelines = timelines):
        for k, a in enumerate(ax):
            a.axis([pos,pos+80,-max(timelines[k])-1, max(timelines[k])+1])
        f.canvas.draw_idle()

    f.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
    plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
    t = np.arange(0.0, len(timelines[0]), 1)

    for k, a in enumerate(ax):
        a.plot(t, timelines[k], lw = 0.55, label=timelines_labels[k])
        a.legend(loc="upper right")
        a.axis([0, 160000, -max(timelines[k])-1, max(timelines[k])+1])

    ax[-1].set_xticks(np.arange(0.0, len(timelines[0])+80000, 80000))

    axpos = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
    spos = Slider(axpos, 'Time (ms)', valmin =0, valmax=800000, valinit=0)
    spos.on_changed(update)
    plt.show()

slide_plot(timelines, timelines_labels)
```

As you see, since my plots are sharing the X-axis, I'm taking out the xticks labels (will do the same with the xticks later) from all the axis except the bottom one.

Then I create the variable t which is just the time, I feel like it is useless, and `ax[k].plot(timelines[k])` would be enough.

I do some more formatting by setting one tick every 80000 points.

And finally, I got the slider. Obviously, the update function does not work. I do not know the correct syntax, nor the right way to achieve this.

Thanks :)

EDIT: By placing the argument `ax = ax` and `timelines = timelines` it seems to start working, however I do not like the look of the function. I'm quite sure a better way exist.

EDIT: Latest script... And the output:

[image: output]

Comment: Your indentation seems screwed, please verify it and fix it. Further, you never call `slide_plot`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque No the indentation is correct. Indeed I didn't had the line with the call... I just build that dummy example with the randoms.

Comment: With the slight change in the EDIT, update doesn't crash. However, the scrollbar doesn't work, and the window is equal to the complete set of points :/

Comment: You may directly use `def update(pos):` and remove the line `pos = spos.val` if you want. However the code as it currently is would already work. Hence the question where and how are you running this?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Interesting. I've started the try with this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001713/plotting-the-data-with-scrollable-x-time-horizontal-axis-on-linux which works once the `axcolors` lines are taken out. I'm using spyder, I've first set `%matplotlib` in the Ipytohn Constrole to open a new windows with the plots. The exammple in the post works, however, we my scenario, the scrolling bar doesn't work.

Comment: Would it work if you set `plt.ioff()` somewhere on top of the script?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've added it after the imports. No change :/

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest What is the most weird is that the `a.axis()` doesn't seems to work. The plot has the 800 000 points drawn on the same windows (thus the slider can't really move I guess). And yet if I just do the for loop and the `a.axis` in the Ipython Console, I got the right figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should only occur in IPython (or Spyder using IPython). The problem is that `plt.show()` will not block and the function `slide_plot` will return. Once it returned, all references to the slider and hence the callbacks are gone.
(The code in [this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001713/plotting-the-data-with-scrollable-x-time-horizontal-axis-on-linux) does not use a function, hence this problem does not occur there.)

A solution is to let the function return a reference to the slider and store it.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

timelines = [np.random.randint(-2, 5, size = 800000),
             np.random.randint(-2, 5, size = 800000), 
             np.random.randint(-2, 5, size = 800000)]
timelines_labels = ["label1", "label2", "label3"]

def slide_plot(timelines, timelines_labels):

    f, ax = plt.subplots(len(timelines), 1, sharex = True)

    def update(pos):
        for k, a in enumerate(ax):
            a.axis([pos,pos+25,-max(timelines[k])-1, max(timelines[k])+1])
        f.canvas.draw_idle()

    f.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
    plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
    t = np.arange(0.0, len(timelines[0]), 1)

    for k, a in enumerate(ax):
        a.plot(t, timelines[k], lw = 0.55, label=timelines_labels[k])
        a.legend(loc="upper right")
        a.axis([0, 25, -max(timelines[k])-1, max(timelines[k])+1])

    ax[-1].set_xticks(np.arange(0.0, len(timelines[0]) / 8000, 10))

    axpos = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
    spos = Slider(axpos, 'Time (ms)', 0.1, 90.0)
    spos.on_changed(update)
    plt.show()
    return spos

slider = slide_plot(timelines, timelines_labels)
```

Alternatively you may configure Spyder not to use its "matplotlib graphics support" under Preferences/IPython/Graphics, disable "Activate support" and start a new IPython console to let this take effect.

Comment: Well thanks a lot, I would never have guessed it x')