# Adding a horizontal scrollbar to plot of matrix having many more columns than rows

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I'm plotting a matrix with many more columns than rows and wish to add a horizontal scrollbar. For a plot of the matrix as a whole, my code so far is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

A = random.rand(8,100)

plt.imshow(A.todense())
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

My actual matrix will have about 60 rows and a few million columns, where the latter denotes time. Ideally, I want to keep the colorbar as one scrolls through the plot.

Comment: After the `todense` the matrix no longer sparse.

Comment: imshow won't accept a sparse matrix as input.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon adapting the answer at [Plotting the data with scrollable x (time/horizontal) axis on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001713/plotting-the-data-with-scrollable-x-time-horizontal-axis-on-linux) I've come up with the following, which relies on a slider widget. A desired option is posed as a question.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

A = np.random.rand(50,5000) 
num_channels=A.shape[0]
num_times=A.shape[1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

plt.imshow(A)
plt.colorbar()

plt.axis([0, 100,0,num_channels-1])

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axpos = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

spos = Slider(axpos, 'time', 0.1, num_times -100.0)

def update(val):
    pos = spos.val
    ax.axis([pos,pos+100,0,num_channels-1])

    # Instead of a fixed window size of 100, I'd like to pass a window size as
    an argument to the function. How to do?

    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

spos.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```