# Sliding window plot using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bioinformatics

I want to plot the number of positions in a sliding window of **1000** and a step of **20** for each sample **(A-D)**.

Interpretation:

- `1`: position exists;
- `NA`: position does not exist.

I have tested a dozen tools in `bash`, `R` and other but I am looking for a `Python` solution.
Your advice please.

```
#This is an example of my data:
window = 1000
step = 20

# Example of dataframe
POSITION        A       B       C       D
1250            1       1       1       1 
1750            NA      1       NA      1
1786            1       NA      1       1
1812            1       1       1       1
1855            1       1       1       1
1896            1       NA      1       NA
2635            NA      1       1       1
1689            1       1       NA      NA
3250            1       1       1       1
3655            1       NA      1       1
3589            NA      1       1       1
```

I am looking for some thing like this:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: do you want plot look like as image you send?

Comment: yes exactly, I want to show SNP density using window and step

Comment: Hello @AEH, I found this question: [Plotting the data with scrollable x (time/horizontal) axis on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001713/plotting-the-data-with-scrollable-x-time-horizontal-axis-on-linux "Plotting the data with scrollable x (time/horizontal) axis on Linux"). I think it might be helpful! Even though the specified OS is Linux, since it is a Python solution as you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using a rolling count, then slice by the step.  After that you can stack the df in order to use the hue parameter of the seaborn lineplot.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'POSITION': [1250,
  1750,
  1786,
  1812,
  1855,
  1896,
  2635,
  1689,
  3250,
  3655,
  3589],
 'A': [1.0, np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, np.nan],
 'B': [1.0, 1.0, np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, np.nan, 1.0],
 'C': [1.0, np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
 'D': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]})



window = 5
step = 2

df = df.set_index('POSITION').rolling(window).count().reset_index().iloc[::step, :]    
df = df.melt(id_vars='POSITION', value_vars=['A','B','C','D'], value_name='polym', var_name='chromop')    
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='POSITION',y='polym',hue='chromop')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Chris for your answer, I tested on my data and it gives all the curves superposed, while I have different NaN in each column. In your script, are the NaN eliminated?